# Docker Postgres container fails on macOS

Tags: postgresql, docker, macos, docker-compose

My docker-compose script builds correctly on Windows10 but fails on macOS Monterey. When running `docker compose up --build` the postgres container will exit on the mac, with the error:

```
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
This user must also own the server process
initdb: error: invalid locale settings; check LANG and LC_* environment variables
```

I think I've narrowed the issue down to the *db.Dockerfile*:

```
FROM postgres:14.4

RUN apt-get update -y -q && \
    apt-get upgrade -y -q && \
    apt-get install git -y -q
```

**Removing the apt-get update, upgrade and git install allows the container to run correctly:**

```
FROM postgres:14.4
```

Here's the docker-compose.yaml file for reference:

```
name: dev-test
services:
  postgres:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./db.Dockerfile
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./dev/db/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/db/
    environment:
      POSTGRES_HOST: "localhost"
      POSTGRES_DB: "test"
      POSTGRES_USER: "testusr"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "password"
      POSTGRES_PORT: 5432

  app:
    ...
```

I require the git install to be able to clone a private repository containing a db backup which will then be used to restore the database.

I've also tried setting the LANG and LC_CTYPE variables as suggested in some related stackoverflow questions I've found, this does not resolve the issue.

**Fix:**
I don't want to add this as an answer since I have no idea why it fixes it and it may be specific to my environment, but removing `apt-get upgrade -y -q` works.

Comment: You don't need a source-control system like `git` to run a relational database.  Given what you've shown, I'd use the unmodified `postgres:14.4` image.

Comment: @DavidMaze Ah yeah, sorry if that wasn't clear in my question, I'll be using git in an .sh file to download a backup from a private repository, then running pg_restore within the db container. I've already done this and it works on Windows but I've not mentioned the specifics as I didn't want to muddy the water around the issue of creating the container. It's not just installing git that is causing the issue though, running apt-get update also causes the container to error and exit.